# Access parent class code in custom ESLint rule

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Scenario:
I want to check that a child class method calls a super class method using super keyword if parent class has such a method.
Example:

```
// parent.ts
class Parent {
   a {
     // super class method
   }
}

// child.ts
class Child extends Parent {
    a { 
       // I want to check if parent class has method a 
       // then the child class should call super.a(). else show a warning
      super.a();
    }
}
```

This felt like a use case for writing a custom ESLint rule. I am not able to check if the parent class has a method with name `a` so far.

Is this possible with ESLint rules? Is custom ESLint rule a good thing to do this or should i use a different approach?